# Android : Border only on corners

Tags: android

In my android app, I need border only on four corners as shown in fig (white colored).

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="6">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cornerbg" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

cornerbg.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/btn_border"
                    android:dashWidth="50dp" // I tried this but not getting expected 
                    android:dashGap="60dp"/>

            </shape>
        </item>
        </layer-list>
```

How can I write xml for this?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Do you need these visible corners to be inside a photo or as a border?

Comment: Create 9.png of that four corner image and put in layout front of your image

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser Inside the border.But i can manage that i dont to write it in xml. I will update my question with axml and xml

Answer (score 4):

Below is the drawable that doesn't depends on the width and height of the rectangle, you can use this drawable for portrait and landscape. Please adjust the width and height of the border :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="8dp"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="8dp"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:gravity="top|right">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="top|right">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="8dp"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|left">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|left">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="8dp"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|right">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|right">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a question of a long time ago, but I had the same problem.

I solved by creating secondary layout and including in my main layout.

I hope this solution can help somebody.

main_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="6">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <include layout="@layout/camera_box_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

camera_box_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <!-- Top horizzontal lines -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <!-- Top vertical lines -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <!-- Bottom horizzontal lines -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <!-- Bottom vertical lines -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe the method I used to accomplish this will work for views that need a transparent background, but it should work in all other cases.  Simply create a drawable resource using the code below and set it as the background of whatever view you'd like to have the "corner only" border.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```